# How can I test my services without affecting my database?

Tags: database, spring, testing, rollback

I'm writing some integration tests for my application in Spring.I want to test some services however they may call some Data Access Objects and new data will be saved in my DB.I have two alternatives to clear every thing in database after testing is complete:

1. Use a temp Database to insert test data there
2. clear all my tables everytime I do a test

however i'm looking for let's say a *clean and forward* way, so that I can use my database without manual cleaning. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you testing the services or are you testing the data access objects?  If the former, you'll want to mock the data access objects with in-memory objects that produce known and predictable behavior.  If the latter, you'll want to include as part of the test setup the setup of the database and then as part of the test cleanup the teardown of the database.  (This makes the integration tests a bit slow, but it guarantees a known stable environment with each test which is important.)

Comment: yeah! good point , I first started using easymock library to mock my DAO objects, however it turned out that it requires some changes in my domain model, as an example I had to extend 'Serializeable' and override IsEqual(), so that when testing the behavior of the program , easymock can reassure that the correct object is passed to a method. Well I preferred not to change my domain model . how can I teardown my database,that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user1948609: As long as you're using a temporary database for testing, *not* a production database, you can probably tear it down with a simple `drop database database-name`. That's what I do in final cleanup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring framework then I think you should have already checked Spring's [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html) on how to do testing.

You'll see that Spring will make it so simple for you, in a way that you don't need to interact with transactions directly.Adding a **@Transactionl** annotation at top of your tests is all you need to do, So what's the benefit of making a test transactional? yes! As mentioned earlier by other answers it will let you rollback your transactions so nothing will remain in your DB. Take a look at this sample code:

```
    @Transactional
    public class FictitiousTransactionalTest {

        @Before
        public void setUpTestDataWithinTransaction() {
            // set up test data within the transaction
        }

        @Test
        @Rollback(true)
        public void modifyDatabaseWithinTransaction() {
            // logic which uses the test data and modifies database state
        }
    }
```

Something important to note is that your database must be InnoDB, So if you are using mySQL which is myISAM by default consider altering your tables beforehand.

Comment: I checked the reference! You were right. I had missed a huge help on that documentation. And thanks for the final note ;) I'll consider that

Answer (score 3):

Responding to the comment on the question with an answer because a comment alone couldn't capture it...

Setting up and tearing down a database between each test can certainly be very costly for performance.  And how you go about doing it depends entirely on the database itself.  (MS SQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.)  If you can get away with swapping out an entirely in-memory database while using the same code then that would be the fastest one to setup and tear down with each test.

As an example, I once had a project where I needed to run my tests against an instance of MS SQL.  The setup and teardown slowed the tests a *lot*, but we all decided it was worth it for the expanded test coverage.  (We ran the integration tests nightly instead of on check-in, so it wasn't a big deal anyway.)  To completely refresh the database, we used this code (C#, sorry):

```
var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    Arguments = string.Format(@"/Action:Publish /SourceFile:{0} /p:CreateNewDatabase=True /TargetConnectionString:""{1}""", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLPackageFile"], ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString),
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    ErrorDialog = false,
    FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLPackageExecutable"],
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = procInfo
};
proc.Start();
```

Then in the configuration for the tests we had three values:

1. The connection string for the database.
2. The command-line executable for MS SQL to do the setup/teardown.
3. The SQL package file that the executable used to do the setup.

So before each test we would run this to completely refresh the database to a known initial state based on the SQL package from source control.  Again, this was *very slow* but it worked.  There may be faster solutions that will work for you.  (Perhaps instead of dropping and re-creating the database you truncate and re-populate tables, or drop and re-create tables, etc.  Tinker with it to find what works for your needs.)

Additionally, we wanted to make sure this fit into our domain model without polluting anything outside of the SQL dependency.  The model we were using for data access was a repository pattern.  Basically our central domain code had domain models (not coupled with DB tables or any other dependencies) and repository interfaces for those models.  Then a data access project implemented those interfaces and internally mapped between the domain models and the database tables/columns.

(We also had two other repository implementation projects for the same interfaces.  One was an in-memory implementation used for domain unit testing.  It simply kept static lists of the models sent to the repository.  The other was an implementation that used XML files per data persistence for running the software without a SQL instance.  Which one was used by any given instance of the application was determined by a configuration setting for the dependency injection container.)

So what we did was add another interface in the domain called `DataResetter`.  Then each data access implementation (SQL, in-memory, XML) implemented that interface.  The SQL one used the above code and config values, the in-memory one just cleared its static lists, and the XML one just deleted the XML files.

This allowed the tests to use domain functionality for the test setup and teardown and allow the dependency injection container to determine which implementation to use.  That way the tests weren't coupled with any particular implementation.  An added benefit to this was that the same tests could be used for unit and integration purposes.  The difference between them was nothing more than a configuration setting.

(First test that the full domain works with in-memory mock implementations, then test the domain again with one dependency implementation, test it again with another, etc.  We ended up running the same suite of tests a dozen times each night for a dozen different dependency implementations throughout the system.  One dependency at a time.  This allowed us to easily see when something was broken because in any given running of the tests there was only one new variable.)

Comment: @ye9ane: I struggled with posting as an answer because it's more of an anecdotal story to give the OP some ideas.  But a comment couldn't contain it.  I can't stress enough that there are multiple ways to accomplish this, nor can I pretend to know anything about Spring or what it may offer for this :)

Answer (score 2):

There's another option: use mocks for the DAOs when you test the services.

Unit testing is different from integration testing.  Unit tests should only be about the class of interest, not all its dependencies.

I'm assuming that you've already unit tested the DAOs in a transactional way, so there's no need to prove that they work properly again.

Another option for integration testing that you didn't mention is to make all your database interactions from the services transactional.  Perform the operations and then roll them back when you're done.

The temp database is an attractive option.  You can use something small and light like Hypersonic or Derby or SQLLite.  The downside is that you have to update your schemas twice: once in the test database and again in the production instance.  It's a wash if you have to do this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is an other Option: Transaction Roleback

Depending on how you open and commit your transaction, it is maybe possible not to commit your transaction and instead do a role back.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `@Transactional` annotation on your test methods, and spring will automatically do rollback.